# How to write XML Schema Instance with VisualBasic?

Tags: xml, vb.net, attributes

I'm doing my first project with VisualBasic. Consists in writing an XML and save it. This is my code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Public Class Form1

Private Sub saveXML_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles saveXML.Click
    Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
    settings.Indent = True


    Dim XmlWrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("C:\Documents and Settings\dpradell\MyName.xml", settings)

    With XmlWrt


        .WriteStartDocument()
        .WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
        .WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
```

And with this part:

```
        .WriteStartElement("Production")
        .WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
        .WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
```

I want to write this declaration:

```
<Production xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

But seems like ":" char is not allowed to be included to the attribute.
How can I solve it?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML namespace declaration, like for example `xmlns:xsd="namespace_uri_here"`, is similar to common XML attributes in namespace. The example consists of `xmlns` as attribute prefix, `xsd` as attribute local-name, and `"namespace_uri_here"` as the attribute value. To write attribute with such description using `XmlWriter`, you can do this way :

```
....
XmlWrt.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsd", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
```

Here is the signature of the method being used above (see the details in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z46xs1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)) :

```
Public Sub WriteAttributeString (
    prefix As String,
    localName As String,
    ns As String,
    value As String
)
```